# Lost data in SQL Server - how do I query log files (maybe fn_dblog(null,null)

Tags: sql, sql-server, logfile

I lost some data. I had a backup, so it's not really lost, but I need to know which stored procedure lost it on me (so I can go back and fix it). I did not have any proper auditing or logging in place at the time of the loss. So I wanted to go back and query SQL Server log files for the 12 hour time frame that I know it got lost in. I was trying to query log files by selecting from `fn_dblog(null, null)`

But I can't figure out how to filter for a date range, nor can I read most of the results. Any ideas anyone?

I'm using SQL Server 2017

Comment: The recommendation here is usually to buy third party log reading software

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid but that is probably driven by sql,  so I’d like to figure that out

Comment: Not sure what you mean but there are a myriad of "how do I decode the log" questions online but there's never an answer